# Session value is destroyed after ajax jquery call to function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

I can't store the new session value and old session value simultaneously, when I pass some value to `function  ResponseOnline($qid,$response)` through ajax jQuery.

Here is my problem

**1**. After login some value store in session

**2**. Then I pass some value to function through ajax jquery and store it in array then in session.

**3**. When I get session value through ajax jquery the I get things right,

**4**. But when I pass second value then I loss my session value which I
    have stored in previous pass.

Here is my function call:

```
public function ResponseOnline($qid,$response)
  {

 $d=$qid;

 $s=$response;

if($this->session->userdata('countnew')==0)   //  algo for this function i check the                                       
                                               //countnew session varaible   if 0 do this 
{                                                
$sc=$this->session->userdata('countnew');     // store the countnew variable
echo $sc=$sc+1;                               // increment the counter variable
$this->session->set_userdata('countnew',$sc);  // store it in session 

echo $this->session->userdata('countnew');
$r2[$d]=$s;                               // store array value $r2 with key $d and 
$this->session->set_userdata('res',$r2);  //set this array value in session 
}
else{                                  // if session countnew!=0 then do this
$r2=$this->session->userdata('res');  // first store $r2 as array return from session
 $r2[$d]=$s;                         //then add value to this array                      

 $this->session->set_userdata('res',$r2); // storing this array to session
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($r2);       // printing the array


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function ResponseOnline($qid,$response)
{
    if($this->session->userdata('res'))
    {
         $result = $this->session->userdata('res');
         $result[$qid] = $response;
         $this->session->set_userdata($result);
    }
    else
    {
         $result = array();
         $result[$qid] = $response;
         $this->session->set_userdata($result);
    }
}
```